# getting access to the listview items in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

i have these lines of codes in my xaml :

> ```
> <ListView x:Name="ContactsList" MouseDoubleClick="ContactsList_MouseDoubleClick" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="453" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
>        <ListView.View>
>             <GridView>
>                  <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
>                  <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" Width="115" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
>             </GridView>
>        </ListView.View>
> </ListView>
> ```

and i got a table of data name Contacts and this is my addContact function :

> ContactDBEntities db = new ContactDBEntities();
>
> ```
> Contact newContact = new Contact();
> newContact.FirstName = FName.Text;
> newContact.LastName = LName.Text;
> newContact.Mobile = Mob.Text;
> newContact.Telephone = Tel.Text;
> newContact.Mail = Mail.Text;
>
> db.Contacts.Add(newContact);
> db.SaveChanges();
> ```

and my show contacts function is :

> ```
> IQueryable<Contact> items = from c in db.Contacts
>                     where c.LastName.Contains(s) ||
>                     c.FirstName.Contains(s)
>                     select c;
> ContactsList.ItemsSource = items.ToList();
> ```

and all i want is to know which object has clicked by the user in listview so i can access to it's information. shoud i use the below function? and if i should what i have to write in it?

> ```
> private void ContactsList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
> {
> }
> ```

Comment: i found my solution by: `var item = ((FrameworkElement) e.OriginalSource).DataContext as Contact;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook the SelectionChanged event to run your function whenever they select a different item.  That way your function will work regardless of the input device they use (keyboard arrows, etc).

Then in your function just read `listView.SelectedIndices` which contains a collection of all selected indices.

If you just want to respond to double-clicks and a single item, stay with MouseDoubleClick and get your item by:
`ListViewItem lvi = listView.SelectedItems[0];`

Comment: i have not selectedIndices and i just want one object by double clicking on that sir

Comment: @Sina Ah, okay.  I have revised my answer, does that help?

Comment: i write this : ListViewItem lvi = contactsList.selectedItems[0]; and it's got and casting error !!

Comment: try `ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)lstView.SelectedItems[0];`

Comment: it seems good but how i can get the mobile attribute of my object? i couldn't find that in lvi attributes

Comment: The ListView will contain a list of ListViewItems, which aren't going to be direct references to your objects.  Rather, they are ListViewItems created using information you have told them to pull from your objects as you specified with "LastName" and "FirstName" in your xaml.  I recommend adding another member to Contact called `id` then add that as a hidden column in your view so that you can pull it with `((ListViewItem)lstView.SelectedItems[0]).SubItems[#];` where # is the index of the `id` column in your grid view.  Then you can do a lookup in your actual list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. In WPF, databinding is treated in a totally different manner, as
   compared to Winforms.
2. If you can follow this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you should be able to accomplish
   what you need, but you need to modify your code.
3. In your case, each item in the ListView is a `Contact` Object, so
       you need to bind the `SelectedItem` property of ListView to a
       property say (SelectedContact) in the class that implements
       `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

   > private Contact _selectedContact;
   >
   > public Contact SelectedContact
   >           {
   >               get
   >               {
   >                   return this._selectedContact;
   >               }
   >
   > ```
   >         set
   >         {
   >             if (value != this._selectedContact)
   >             {
   >                 this._selectedContact= value;
   >                 NotifyPropertyChanged();
   >             }
   >         }
   >     }
   > ```
4. Word of advice : If you are not using Data binding and Property Changed via INotifyPropertyChanged  functionality then you are still living in the old world of WindowsForm world. I would request you to learn it and adapt in your code.